# How do I test whether differences in populations are significant?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, sample-size, mean, inference

I'm working on a large database. I want to explore whether certain batch jobs run in more or less time after a change was than they did before the change.

There are about 90 distinct batch jobs. They run according to different timetables, so some of them are called only once a week, and some are called hundred of times per day. I have data for a three-month period before the change was made, and a one-week period since then. Each distinct batch job has run a different number of times before and after the change being investigated.

Currently I am using a two-sample z-test, as described here:
http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~cochran/stat10/winter/lectures/lect21.html

For each distinct batch job, I have sample size, mean run time, and standard deviation, both before and after the change. So I'm calculating a z-value, based on a null hypothesis that the two populations have the same mean and s.d. The resulting z-values range from -35 to +10.

My question is, is this the right statistical test for this situation? I believe that the z-values tell me how many standard deviations away from a mean result, given the null hypothesis, my new (post-change) population is. I believe I can use that information to identify the batch jobs that have been most affected by the change (accepting that correlation ! => causation).

Am I doing the right test? Have I understood the meaning of the data correctly, and what I can infer from it?

Comment: Why aren't you using a two-sample t-test on the individual observations? That seems to be what's recommended by the author of the web-page you cite.

Comment: I second @Ben's comment.  Also, what the z-statistics (or t-statistics) tell you deals with standard *errors* of the difference between the two sets of jobs.

Comment: @Ben - mostly because I don't know how to do one!

Comment: @rolando2 - I want to be sure I understand what you're telling me. Is this the distinction I should be concerned with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_mean_versus_standard_deviation?

Comment: @James - That's right.

Comment: @James, if you are an `R` user, you could post a question on stackoverflow.com to get some 'how to' advice. Or just have a look around online, there are a lot of relevant tutorials and videos: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=t-test+in+R